# Theoretical unbreakable security for a single compute instance/machine

Tags: hardening, physical-access

*UPDATE : i know i modify the post significantly, will try to not do that anymore. Please read from scratch*

Let's imagine we have a machine that holds **customer private keys to various crypto assets**, that is vital to secure and should it be compromised it's going to be fatal for the enterprise.

My goal as software engineer (who is not particularly experienced in infosec) is to minimise possible ways an attacker could tackle my system. The approach here is that i assume everything is insecure and i should not use it unless i absolutely have to.

**I would like you to explain how would you attack it?** I'll clarify more details as you ask them but for now here is what i think i would do and why i would do it that way. If you think something is redundant or unnecessary please comment too thats valuable input as well.

1. The machine is running minimal linux and is hosting several services on prem.
2. None of the services use any databases or frameworks or mainstream libraries, only language SDK (which is 20+years old in prod systems). I do this so that i'm not subjected to any vulnerabilities that come with such things.
3. All incomming connection to this machine are rejected, to update anything it must be accessed directly. This is obvoiusly so that no one can port scan or even access it even if they somehow obtain valid key or find out where this machine is.
4. One of the services does all the interaction with the world trough  **telegram bot api** (by initiating https requests to poll for new updates), few **crypto exchanges** and **blockchains**. In all cases it initiates the interaction and parses the response into an equivalent very strict binary message which another service on the same host will consume. The binary format only uses fixed length fields so one cannot simply reply with 2GB string (assuming one of those 3rd parties is compromised) and expect application to actually try and parse that... an attacker frankly cannot even know where this machine is because its not publicly reachable unless attacker can compromise either telegram or binance (blockchains wont know who i am).
5. Attacker will know my identity and that i'm behind the system.

At this point i naively think that i'm safe from digital ways of hacking into it and i'm thinking towards how would i work with this setup with all the restrictions. After all no one can know where the machine is since its not publicly reachable, even if they hacked into telegram and can directly meddle with the response and send something out of ordinary it will fail to deserialize, they cannot just use  the https connection to do anything interesting (maybe i'm wrong?), best they can do is try and reply with various injection payloads all of which will fail.

In order for me to update the software i have to access it in person, but that makes me a single point of failure. Someone could target a family member and get me to cooperate. So from this point i assume that someone is willing to go that far and i'm 100% cooperating. So think i'm your hostage and i'm doing as you say.

To prevent single point of failure what i could do is have 4-5 other individuals who have same access level as i have, meaning they can pass the in person verification in the building and to the server room (or wherever the machine is). To access it i need at least N-1 keys at the same time. If someone from the company leaves this majority can update the system to remove that key from the chain.

This makes updating it a pain and a stupid ritual but i think it is the safest way. So the attacker would have to capture me, find out the names of the others involved and go after them...

If we want to update it frequently we could come up with an approach where the machine has N trusted publicly visible locations where it will pull an image of the next version of software. Each person knows and picks the location but does not know the location or keys to access others, so once we have a build of the software that we agree needs to roll out we could all locally build it, upload to our specific servers, and let the system pick it up.

Each image is encrypted with the key of the owner and will be decrypted once downloaded on the machine, if decrypted images all do not match up all of them get discarded. This is just some means to update the software without getting each person into the server room, but still forcing attackers to go after each one...

Comment: Especially point 2 and 4 heavily rely on the security of the processes involved - without going into detail on how these can be guaranteed. For example in point 2 there is the clear risk of introducing a back door through an update at an early point in the supply chain, so that all involved in your scenario will actually publish the same compromised update. And in point 4 "identity is checked" is too weakly defined too. Also introducing too much steps for access might also result in authorized users not getting access in critical situations - so there is a trade-off.

Comment: #3 requires you to design a new network protocol?

Comment: I'm not sure if this type of open-ended question works on a Q&A site. In your 4 points, you're trying to cover secure configuration, secure maintenance processes, network-level security, and physical security. These are all good areas to consider, but how is the community supposed to provide complete and comprehensive answers for all those areas (and others you haven't mentioned!)

Comment: Instead, look at existing frameworks that will help you design the security you need. Like the CIS Top 20 controls, and the NIST CSF. These will help you consider the different areas of security.

Comment: 1. introducing backdoor? how the software of the service itself is updated only not the OS, unless all parties involved are corrupt at the same time its not possible... it must be either an accident or someone internally getting malicious code past review process and into the system...

Comment: 3. does not require any new protocols as i said use plain simple https and wss, the other end needs to know the message format because content is not text but binary...

Comment: I'll update the question to make it more specific, think of it as here is my system, how would you attack it?

Comment: Besides the fact that the question has been significantly altered, it is now closed so it cannot accept answers. Aside from that, the comments from people suggest that it is difficult for us to provide assistance with so many known (and unknown) unknowns and that you should focus on using a well established security framework in order to find answers, rather that trying to cherry-pick advices from this forum.

Comment: One last thing, you put too much emphasis on user space vulnerabilities compared to the kernel space ones. Every network packet reaching your box will first have to go through the kernel network stack before its fate is decided. At this point, it's already too late if a packet read by the kernel is crafted to exploit a zero day vulnerability targeting the network stack. My suggestion would be that you should focus more on incident response, disaster recovery and crisis management, rather than trying to prevent something highly probable.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** There is no such thing as theoretical unbreakable security. Nor a practical one.

Everything depends on the resources (time and money) available to the attacker and the defender. The one with more resources always wins.

As such, the theoretical answer to your question is: you can't achieve what you're looking for. The practical answer is: before you implement any solution, you first need to follow the correct process:

1. identify what you need to protect - your assets and their values to your business
2. establish a threat model (who is your attacker, attack surface, counter measures and risk assessment)
3. establish a security policy (based on the threat model)

You have done step (1), you lack step (2) and you need an advice on step (3). That's difficult to answer.

Here are some thoughts to get you started:

- Who's your attacker? Is it me (a random guy) or a highly motivated and skilled, state sponsored, adversary?
- What's your attack surface? Without this, you can't identify counter measures and, as such, every solution may have little to no actual (positive) impact on the overall security of the system
- Implementing counter measures costs money and time. You need to make a risk assesment in order to prioritize your counter measures; unless you're a high value organization that you absolutely must protect all your assets against all identified threats and at all cost, then you would want to address the most probable and high impact attack vectors first, rather than addressing what *seem like* good candidates

Aside from the general guidance, let's explore your solution:

1. Attack surface: you don't allow incoming connections to the box, but you do allow *incoming data to your software*. That's a game changer; the moment you allow a third party (outside of your *trust* and *security domains*) to provide you with data, that's the moment you allow for that party to exploit your software. It doesn't matter that the connections are initiated by your box - it's the data that matter. They may well be malformed, exploit a vulnerability on your software and establish a reverse shell to an attacker's box
2. (a) what happens when/if one of them resigns? Or if a person is sick and you need access to your box? How will that impact your business? Or (b) what happens if a malicious third party always provides a broken image to your box with the intent that the latter always rejects new updates (a form of Denial of Service for the software update mechanism)? Then your box will stay unpatched for who knows how long (which will increase the window of opportunity for exploitation)
3. That's security through obscurity. I don't necessarily disagree with obscuring your security practices, as long as it's just one more step made on top of other, *sound*, practices. You can't exclude insider threats; i.e. people that know the structure that reveal it to a third party. People get sloppy. Or disgruntled. Or even don't share your concerns on what's important to protect and what not
4. Too vague to comment on; identity and access management is a broad subject and is not bullet proof. Again, people get sloppy. Or don't share your concerns. And, in the end of the day, people get tricked in all sorts of ways (social engineering). Finally, someone could just break in during the night, through a window of the room that hosts your box. It all depends on your threat model.

A couple more thoughts on your questions:

- "*Assuming that there are no security issues that one can exploit with the OS*" is like asking: "*if there's no way someone can hack me, how can anyone hack me?*". Not realistic.
- "*is there anything an attacker can do other than kidnap every single person involved*": yes. Grab the box and run. Copy or steal the hard disk. Set the building on fire. Again, what's your threat model?
- "*what would you do differently if you had to make sure this one machine is never ever breached unless all people involved are compromised*": encrypt everything with a strong algorithm, then throw away the randomly generated key without keeping a backup, nor having any way to restore it, then put the box in a room that has no doors, windows or cables going in or out of the room (be it power or internet ones) and let it be

In principle, security should not be implemented just for the sake of it; it needs to protect the target assets *and* let the business operate undisrupted. Else it does not serve its purpose.

Anyway, I would suggest that you came up with a good threat model. Then, it should be fairly straight forward to find the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Ok regarding "Who's your attacker?", lets say my service holds private keys to wallets of millions of customers to different assets they own (lets say for this example its crypto) so attacker has monetary incentive to crack the box to access those keys... Service itself never exposes the keys, they can only be added by the user directly via https (where service is the one making the https request)...

Comment: Alright i totally get the data part and exploiting software, that i believe i have good solution for. Even though i do not trust the third party directly, i have very strict validations, there are no databases involved, so no injections, and i do not use any libraries other than SDK of the language. My goal is to keep the service as simple as possible.

Comment: OK i've updated the question please give another read? appreciate the effort in either case )